# Weblogic12 - start Admin Server throws syntax error

Tags: batch-file, cmd, weblogic

I have a big problem with Weblogic12. I tried to run Admin Server and the command line just disappear without any information. So I was debugging it deeper and there is a problem in shortenPaths.cmd file which looks like:

```
@rem **************************************************************************
@rem This script is used to shorten CLASSPATH and PATH environmental variables.
@rem 
@rem Copyright (c) 2011, 2016, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved. 
@rem **************************************************************************
if NOT "%CLASSPATH%"=="" (
  call :handle_classpath
)

if NOT "%PATH%"=="" (
  call :handle_path
)
goto :EOF

:handle_classpath
pause
  set __SHORT_CLASSPATH__=
  call :process_classpath "%CLASSPATH%"
  set CLASSPATH=%__SHORT_CLASSPATH__%
  goto :EOF

:handle_path
  set __SHORT_PATH__=
  call :process_path "%PATH%"
  set PATH=%__SHORT_PATH__%
  goto :EOF

:process_classpath
  FOR /F "TOKENS=1,* DELIMS=;" %%a IN (%1) DO (
    if NOT "%%a"=="" (
      if exist "%%a" (
        call :add_to_classpath %%~fsa
      )
    )
    if NOT "%%b"=="" (
      call :process_classpath "%%b"
    )
  )
  goto :EOF

:add_to_classpath
  if NOT "%1"=="" (
    if NOT "%__SHORT_CLASSPATH__%"=="" (
      set __SHORT_CLASSPATH__=%__SHORT_CLASSPATH__%;%1
    ) else (
      set __SHORT_CLASSPATH__=%1
    )
  )
  goto :EOF

:process_path
  FOR /F "TOKENS=1,* DELIMS=;" %%a IN (%1) DO (
    if NOT "%%a"=="" (
      if exist "%%a" (
        call :add_to_path %%~fsa
      )
    )
    if NOT "%%b"=="" (
      call :process_path "%%b"
    )
  )
  goto :EOF

:add_to_path
  if NOT "%1"=="" (
    if NOT "%__SHORT_PATH__%"=="" (
      set __SHORT_PATH__=%__SHORT_PATH__%;%1
    ) else (
      set __SHORT_PATH__=%1
    ) 
  )
```

Command line throws this error:

```
if NOT "" == "" (call :handle_classpath )
The syntax of the command is incorrect.
```

So I tried to simulate the same if statement in my own script:

```
set CLASSPATH=""

if NOT "%CLASSPATH%"=="" (
  echo "inside"
)
pause
```

And the result is :

```
C:\Tools\Weblogic12\oracle_common\common\bin>if NOT """" == "" (echo "inside" )
"inside"

C:\Tools\Weblogic12\oracle_common\common\bin>pause
Press any key to continue . . .
```

I have no idea what is going on with this Weblogic. I didn't do anything just try to test my application and I cannot start it. Two days ago it works fine without any problems. The most reflecting is why command line throw error in Weblogic script and the same situation in my own works fine.

Comment: Since you suspect the classpath, how about you set the classpath first (say by executing setDomainEnv.sh ) and then start admin server (I am assuming you are using startWebLogic.sh )

Comment: That's right, I start weblogic using startWebLogic.cmd but the command line just disappear so, I start to debug this and I stopped at this problem. That's weird because I didn't do anything with it, and it just stopped working. startWebLogic.cmd call setDomainEnv.cmd which call another file I don't remember, and cannot check it now cause I'm not in work, and that file call shortenPath.cmd which cause that problem

Comment: If these are the files provided by Oracle it would be very strange if they do not work - unless they have been changed....but I guess you have already confirmed that nothing got changed.

Comment: And yes, since you are on Windows, its .cmd not .sh !

Comment: Two days ago it worked fine, and I just didn't do anything with it, because I didn't work with java so I didn't have to deploy application. Now I have to check something and tried to start server the same like before without any changes and it doesn't work. I'm wondering if there was any update which could made some problems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found solution. There was a problem with Path environment variable. When I check it with using GUI and when I print it in console there was differences. In console system add path to microsoft .net framework which contains at the end quotation marks which causes problems. The most important is when I add something to Path using GUI and delete it there was no more that weird path to microsoft .net and it started to work correctly...